# How to build this swap button within input fields in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Look at the UI above. How can I build this swap circle in flutter (mobile).

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

```
Stack
  Column
    TextField
    TextField
  Positioned
    right,
    Container with BoxShape.circle and blue border
```